# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value

Tags: java, sql

SERVİCE:

```
public Page<ExportDto> findBySearch(FirmDto firm, List<String> product1, List<String> country1, ExDocumentTypeDto exDocumentType, Date documentDate, Date documentDateEnd, String documentSerial, String invoiceNumber, CurrencyGtoDto currencygto, Pageable pageable) {
   if(firm.getId()!=null ) { 
      parametre=parametre +  "p.firm.id=:" + firm.getId();
   }
   Page<Export> exports =  dao.findBySearchDao(pageable,parametre); 
}
```

DAO:

```
 @Query("SELECT p FROM Export p WHERE p=:parametre")
 Page<Export> findBySearchDao(Pageable pageable, @Param("parametre") String parametre);
```

Comment: can you tell what help you are looking for?

Comment: Put your question into words